# How to reduce the file size of GeoJSON data?

Tags: geojson, ogr2ogr, tiger, topojson

For my project I am trying to convert the tiger shapefile information for us states into GeoJSON format

However when I use the ogr2ogr tool the data file is about 20 MB. I have seen the geoJSON file of US States [elsewhere](https://github.com/mbostock/bost.ocks.org/blob/gh-pages/mike/leaflet/us-states.json) of around 88KB.

How do I reduce the output to geoJSON file?

Answer (score 7):

You have two ways of reducing the file size:

1. Remove all the pretty formatting and redundant white space.  In some 'XML-style' files this can be a surprisingly large amount and can easily double or even treble your file size.  However I doubt it accounts for the difference in your volume and the data you link to above.
2. Reduce the volume of actual data either by reducing your coordinate precision (e.g. 6 decimal places vs say 12) and/or reducing the actual number of vertices representing the features in your data.  I suspect that this accounts for a substantial proportion of the difference in file sizes you are seeing.  Much depends on your use-case for how much simplification will be acceptable and only you can decide that.

Comment: Yes I've read about it here - http://blog.thematicmapping.org/2012/11/how-to-minify-geojson-files.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+thematicmapping+%28thematic+mapping+blog%29

Answer (score 2):

Removing properties and simplifying lines are the easiest ways if you want just GeoJSON, [TopoJson](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson) an modified version of GeoJson and can get some very small sized files especially if you [keep it projected](http://bl.ocks.org/calvinmetcalf/5568668)